# Android Studio using Darcula and setting it to default doesn't change it

Tags: android-studio

I set the theme to darcula but now when I set it to default it doesn't change back. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to uninstall Android Studio and delete the .AndroidStudio folder then reinstall. This turned out to be a bug with that version of Android Studio, normally this wouldn't require a complete reinstall but in this case it did.